# ifort MPICH MPI_GATHERV not working

Tags: fortran, mpi

I am trying to use the `MPI_GATHERV` command, but it does not work for me. The result I am expecting is [0 0 0 0 5 1 1 1 5, 1 0 0 0 5 1 1 1 5] for MYID and a_total, but this is what I got [0 0 0 5 5 5 5 5 5, 1 0 0 5 5 5 5 5 5]. I tried different computers but got the same results.

```
program test
    use MPI
    implicit none
    integer:: IERR,NPROC,MYID
    integer(kind=8),allocatable:: a(:),a_number(:),a_start(:),a_total(:)
    integer:: i,j,k


call MPI_INIT(IERR)

call MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD,NPROC,IERR)

call MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD,MYID,IERR)

allocate(a(3),a_number(NPROC),a_start(NPROC))

allocate(a_total(8))

a=MYID

do i=1,NPROC
    a_number(i)=3
end do 

write(*,*) MYID,a

do i=1,NPROC

    a_start(i)=(i-1)*4

end do


a_total=5


CALL MPI_GATHERV (a(1),3,MPI_INTEGER,&
                  a_total,a_number,a_start,MPI_INTEGER,&
                  0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,IERR)

call MPI_BCAST(a_total,8,MPI_INTEGER,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,IERR)


write(*,*) MYID,a_total

deallocate(a,a_number,a_start,a_total)

call MPI_FINALIZE(IERR)


end program
```

Comment: What kind of result did you get then?

Comment: 0  0  0 5 5 5 5 5 5,
1  0  0 5 5 5 5 5 5
This is what I got for the output of MYID and a_total.

Comment: You can use the more efficient `MPI_ALLGATHERV` instead of a combination of `MPI_GATHERV` and `MPI_BCAST`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There may be other problems in the code, but one is obvious.

`integer(kind=8)` is some non-portable kind of integer, but is very likely to be larger than the default `integer`.

You are using `MPI_INTEGER` as the MPI type, but that refers to the default integer (most likely 4 bytes long). You must use the appropriate MPI type. `MPI_INTEGER8` is likely to work, but it is not 100% sure as `integer(kind=8)` is a non-portable declaration, it does not have to be 8 bytes long.

---

If you want an 8 byte integer, it is better to do

```
use iso_fortran_env
integer(int64) :: a
```

Comment: Hi Vladimir F, I changed integer(kind=8) to integer, and it is working! Thank you very much!